# Allow user to drop item in two different droppable areas inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I do have a loop of droppable areas where user is able to drop items. Size of the loop can be different. It depends on user's input. You can check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/97u0peju/236/)
Here is my droppable area:

```
$(".projLeader ol").droppable({ 
tolerance: 'pointer', 
hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui)
    {
         var zz = ui.draggable.text()
         var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
       if (xyz === false) 
       {
          var item = ui.draggable;
          if (!ui.draggable.closest('.placeholder').length) item = item.clone().draggable();// if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
          //this.innerHTML = '';                                                                                // clean the placeholder
          item.addClass('dropClass').appendTo(this); 
          // append item to placeholder   
          //add to array
          itm.push(zz);
          var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
          $(this).closest("div.proc").find("h6").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");

       }
       else 
       {
                alert('Name is Already Exist');
         }

    }
});
```

The problem is I got warning message for each field. For example if I drop item in box1 and then want to drop same item in box2 I got warning message. How can I fix it? Thanks for any help

Comment: when you say you get a wanring you mean the alert message?? also what do you want it to do instead? do you want the program to allow user to drop same item in both boxes

Comment: @HenryDev yes alert message. And yes I want to allow user drop same item in two different boxes but not in the same box.

Comment: the problem is that you are using the SAME array (itm) to store the values. You need 2 arrays to check for each box

Comment: @HenryDev the thing is i can have more than two boxes. number of boxes is the user's input. he sets how many boxes to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time understanding your code and here's the solution. I added some code to detect if an existing box already exists.Hope it helps :)!

```js
var itm = [];
   $( "#savebutton" ).click(function() { LISTOBJ.saveList(); });
   $("#myAccordion").accordion({heightStyle:"content", active: false, collapsible:true});
            $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone", 
        start: function(ev, ui){ ui.helper.width($(this).width()); } 
            });
      
    $(".projLeader ol").droppable({ 
    tolerance: 'pointer', 
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
        drop: function(ev, ui)
        {
             var zz = ui.draggable.text()
             var xyz = itm.includes(zz);
           if (xyz === false) 
           {
              var item = ui.draggable;
              var map = {}, i , size;
              var flag = false;

              if (!ui.draggable.closest('.placeholder').length){ 
              item = item.clone().draggable();// if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
              //this.innerHTML = '';                                                                                // clean the placeholder
               item.addClass('dropClass').appendTo(this); 
              // append item to placeholder   
              //add to array
              var n = $(this).closest("div.proc").find(".dropClass").length;
              $(this).closest("div.proc").find("h6").text("Items Dropped: " + n + ".");
              var listOfElements = $(this).closest("div.proc").find("li").text();
              var newarr =  listOfElements.split('x');
              newarr.shift();
              var actualArrayLength = newarr.length; 
              for (i = 0, size = newarr.length; i < size; i++){
                if (map[newarr[i]]){
                xyz = true;
                alert("Name is Already Exist");
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("h6").text("Items Dropped: " + (n - 1) + ".");
                $(this).closest("div.proc").find("li:last-child").remove();
                return false;
                }   
                else{
                  map[newarr[i]] = true;
                  newarr[newarr.length - 1];
                }           
              }

             }
           }        
        }
    });
    $(".projLeader").on('click', '.closer', function(){
        var item = $(this).closest('.item');
        itm.splice(item);
        item.fadeTo(200, 0, function(){ item.remove(); })
    });
    
            var LISTOBJ = {
            saveList: function() {
                var listCSV = "";
                $( ".projLeader li" ).each(function() {
                    if (listCSV === "") {
                        listCSV = $(this).text();
                    } else {
                        listCSV += ", " + $(this).text();
                    }
          $("#output").text(listCSV);
                    $(".hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
                });
            }
        }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ol{list-style-type: none;}
.item { height:20px; width: 180px; margin:5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid gray; background-color: #cd8; position: relative; }
.item .closer { position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 2px; font: bold 14px arial; color: #666; padding: 1px 3px; line-height: 1; cursor: pointer; display: none;}
.item .closer:hover { color: #000; }


.placeholder { height: 30px; width: 195px; margin: 5px; background: #eee; border: 1px dashed #999; }
.placeholder .item { margin: 0; }
ol .item .closer { display: block; }

.highlight { border: 1px solid red;  background: #fff; }
.highlight .item { opacity: 0.3; }

.ui-draggable-dragging { z-index: 99; opacity: 1 !important; }

.dropClass {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>
<div id="myAccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Lolcat Shirt</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Buckit Shirt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Bags</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Zebra Striped</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Black Leather</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>Alligator Leather</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPhone</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPod</li>
      <li class="item"><span class="closer">x</span>iPad</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='proc'><pre>
<h6> </h6><br /></pre>
  <div class="projLeader">
  <label>Box1:</label>   
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol id = "ID1">
          <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"></li>
          <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
        </ol>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='proc'><pre>
<h6> </h6><br /></pre>
  <div class="projLeader">
  <label>Box2:</label>   
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol id = "ID2" >
          <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"></li>
          <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput2" />
        </ol>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

<input type="submit" id="savebutton" class="button" value="Save" onclick="userSubmitted = true;" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping:)

Comment: One problem, when im trying to drop same item to the box it shows alert  message and doesnt add it to the box but it still counts as item in 'items dropped'

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy I updated my answer to keep track of "items dropped". I'm glad it helped you :)